# condition statement in ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Im using Codeigniter MVC framework and im struggling with Jquery Ajax.
My Questions is how do you put a conditional statements inside the ajax success function?

Basically what I want to do is upon successful entry it will redirect to another page if not will show an error of: Mobile Number does not match or if empty Please fill up the blank.

Controller method

```
if($mobile_number == "") {
                    $data = array('message' => "Please fill up the blanks", 'success' => 'no');

            }
            elseif($mobile_number != "123") {
                    $data = array('message' => "Please does not match", 'success' => 'no');

            }else {
                    #redirect('home/test');
                    $data = array('message' => "Mobile match.", 'success' => 'yes');
            }
            $output = json_encode($data);
            echo $output;
```

my_ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#request_submit").click( 

function(){

    var mobtel=$("#mobtel").val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post_action",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "mob_tel="+mobtel, 
    cache:false,
    success: function (data) {

            if(data.success == 'yes') {
                    $("#form_message").html(data.message).fadeIn('slow'); 
            }
            else if(data.success == 'no') {
                    alert('error');
            }
    }

    });
});
});
```

Thanks in advance. Hope someone can help me here. (T_T)

Comment: I don't think you should trim `data` since it already is an parsed object and not a string.

Comment: Moreover your second `if` statement in your success function should be and `else if` statement instead since `data.success` can't be both `'yes'` and `'no'`

Comment: updated my code. still it ain't working. You can view my site: http://apps.stratpoint.com:9114/home/request_verification/

Comment: try adding exit after echo $output; in your php code

Comment: Use my [jsfiddle example function](http://jsfiddle.net/zmtuk/) to log in the console the structure of the data object, check what is actually returned by the server.

Comment: added exit(); still no change. I can't get the response of my json. Really new to this jquery ajax.

Comment: @MMM - im using a Codeigniter MVC Framework. Where will I put my controller method or my php function?

Comment: Simply paste in the function I've prepared for you to any js file and then call it like `console.log(concatObject(data));`. This will log the structure of the data object that was returned by the server, so you'll make sure that you are actually getting a valid object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question well... From what I got this should nudge to the proper direction.

If I were you, I'd change my response to the following format:

```
$data = array(
 'message'=> /* Your message */,
 'success' => /* True or false */, 
 'case'=> /* 1,2,3 something unique to tell the cases apart */,);

echo json_encode($data);
```

So, in jQuery I can simply do this:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "post_action",
   dataType: "json",
   data: "mob_tel="+mobtel, 
   cache:false,
   success: function (data) {

        switch(data.case){
        1: /*First case */
        break;
        2: /*Second... */
        break;
        3: /* You know the drill... */
        break;
        default:
        /* If none of the above */

        }
}

});
```

Since there are three cases in your code, it's best practice to handle them as three cases. More solid code, and less error prone.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Controller method:

At the end of function use `exit();`

In my_ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#request_submit").click( 

function(){

    var mobtel=$("#mobtel").val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post_action",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "mob_tel="+mobtel, 
    cache:false,
    success: function (data) {

            if(data.success == 'yes') {
                    $("#form_message").html(data.message).fadeIn('slow'); 
            }
            else{

                  if(data.message == "Please does not match"){ 
                    //show error message where ever you want
                      $("#form_message").html(data.message).fadeIn('slow'); 
                  }else{
                    //Do whatever you want to do :: to redirect can use window.location
                       alert('data.message')
                   }

            }
    }

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure about CI, but in some cases u will need to clean the output buffer before echoing the response to the ajax call. this can be sone by using ob_clean();

Comment: If any error is shown either in javascript or in php? Please let me know the error..Use Error console..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop to search for any keys in the callback object

If you want to see if an error key exists in the callback you could use:

```
success: function(cb)
{
    for(errors in cb)
    {
       //checking for error key in the callback
    }
}
```